# Добавление второй сцены FXML JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Всем привет! Пишу файловый менеджер. Хочу добавить вторую сцену и прописываю ' <fx:include source="vk2.fxml"/>' сцена в этом случае накладывается на первую и перекрывает все, что было в первой. Как добавить вторую сцену, что бы она дополнила первую, не перекрывая элементы[![На этой картинке,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] место вставки второй сцены[image: Мой код fxml. место вставки второй сценымой результат]

[image: без вставки второй сцены]

Comment: Насколько мне известно, сцена может быть только одна( в неё не могут быть вложены другие сцены) но вы можете вызвать сцену как модальное окно. Проще описать какой нибудь контейнер, и в него ложить все ваши элементы.

Comment: Я по видео уроку делаю, там у препода получилось вроде